# iOS playing audio in iOS 13 throws C++ exception, freezes app

Tags: swiftui, freeze, avaudioplayer

### TL;DR:

The code below (all ten lines of it, apart from debugging)

- fails (UI freezes)  on iOS 13.x (Simulator)
- succeeds (audio plays) on 14.x  (Simulator and devices)

I don't have any devices with iOS 13.x. But...analytics from live apps suggest it is failing in the field on *both* iOS 13 and 14 *devices*. False positives? (See line of code commented with $$$.)

### Steps To Reproduce

Create a new SwiftUI project that can run in iOS 13. Replace the text in `ContentView.swift` with the code below. Add an audio resource named `clip.mp3`. Build and run.

I am using Xcode 12.4, macOS 11.1, Swift 5.

### See Also

- [Apple Dev Forum 1](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/667921)   // Unresolved
- [Apple Dev Forum 2](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/650741)   // Attributed to beta iOS/Xcode
- [Stackoverflow 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66077123)    // Unresolved
- [Stackoverflow 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62587118)   // Refers to next link
- [Apple Dev Forum 3](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/651353)   // Claims fixed in Xcode 12b5 
  [...and many more...]

### Code

```
import SwiftUI
import AVKit

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Boo!").onAppear { playClip() }
    }
}

var clipDelegate: AudioTimerDelegate!   // Hold onto it to forestall GC.
var player      : AVAudioPlayer!        // Ditto.

func playClip() {
    let u = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "clip", withExtension: "mp3")!
    player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: u)
    clipDelegate = AudioTimerDelegate()  // Wait till now to instantiate, for correct timing.
    player.delegate = clipDelegate
    player.prepareToPlay()
    NSLog("*** Starting clip play")    // NSLog so we get timestamp.
    player.play()

    // Wait 5 seconds and see if audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying.
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
        if let d = clipDelegate.clipDuration {
            NSLog("*** Caller   clip duration = \(d)")
        } else {
            NSLog("!!! Caller found nil clip duration")
            // $$$ In live app, post audio-freeze event to analytics.
        }
    }
}

class AudioTimerDelegate: NSObject, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {
    private var startTime : Double
    var clipDuration: Double?
    override init() {
        self.startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
        super.init()
    }
    func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
        clipDuration = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime
        NSLog("*** Delegate clip duration = \(clipDuration!)")
    }
}
```

### Console Output

**Simulator iOS 14.4**

The audio plays and the Console (edited for brevity) reads:

```
14:33:17  [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for ... F8BB1C28-...
14:33:17  *** Starting clip play
14:33:19  *** Delegate clip duration = 1.692...
14:33:22  *** Caller   clip duration = 1.692...
```

I gather that the first line is innocuous and related to the Simulator's sound drivers.
[Is anyone else getting this console message with AVAudioPlayer in Xcode 11 (and 11.1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58279150)

**Device 14.4**

Results are the same, without the `AddInstanceForFactory` complaint.

**Simulator 13.6**

Audio never sounds, the delegate callback never runs, and in the Console I get:

```
14:30:10  [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for ... F8BB1C28-...
14:30:11  HALB_IOBufferManager_Client::GetIOBuffer: the stream index is out of range
14:30:11  HALB_IOBufferManager_Client::GetIOBuffer: the stream index is out of range
14:30:11  [aqme] AQME.h:254:IOProcFailure: AQDefaultDevice (1): output stream 0: null buffer
14:30:11  [aqme] AQMEIO_HAL.cpp:1774:IOProc: EXCEPTION thrown (-50): error != 0

14:30:26  [aqme] AQMEIO.cpp:179:AwaitIOCycle: timed out after 15.000s (0 1); suspension count=0 (IOSuspensions: )
14:30:26  CA_UISoundClient.cpp:241:StartPlaying_block_invoke: CA_UISoundClientBase::StartPlaying: AddRunningClient failed (status = -66681).
14:30:26  *** Starting clip play
14:30:26  HALB_IOBufferManager_Client::GetIOBuffer: the stream index is out of range
14:30:26  HALB_IOBufferManager_Client::GetIOBuffer: the stream index is out of range
14:30:26  [aqme] AQME.h:254:IOProcFailure: AQDefaultDevice (1): output stream 0: null buffer
14:30:26  [aqme] AQMEIO_HAL.cpp:1774:IOProc: EXCEPTION thrown (-50): error != 0

14:30:41  [aqme] AQMEIO.cpp:179:AwaitIOCycle: timed out after 15.000s (1 2); suspension count=0 (IOSuspensions: )
14:30:46  !!! Caller found nil clip duration
```

**Remarks**

It seems that there are *two* fifteen-second delays going on in the failure case.

Comment: FWIW, I see this behavior on iOS 12/13 simulators, but it appears to work on actual iOS 13.4 device. (FWIW, I’m using `AVPlayer` and `AVPlayerLayer`, playing video, but I'm assuming it is the same issue as the above. Exact same errors.) Looks like a simulator bug to me, though I don't see this explicitly addressed in the [Xcode release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes).

Comment: Thanks Rob, I am hoping that is the case. DTS asked me to file a feedback, which I did at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback/9012209. I am still getting analytics from live apps that wind up at the `$$$` line of code, so i am still worried. This code does run correctly on BitBar's free iPhone SE 2020 A2296 13.4.1 though.

Comment: I've started seeing the same thing. Just one of many, many spurious warnings and errors that the simulator is barfing and drowning out the debugging output that I want to see.

Comment: I discussed this with Apple in a WWDC lab. Their perspective was: 1) Known bug on Simulator. 2) If it were widely prevalent in live devices, we would all know. 3) My 5 second delay may be too tight for the first time a 3-second clip plays, due to one-time startup costs, leading to false positives 4) I could try using`AVAudioSession` to hint to the OS about what is ahead. Will add to this when/if I have more results.